# Video tutorials for Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: c#, .net, wif

Is there a series of webcasts for Windows Identity Foundation. I don't seem to find any that talks about WIF in depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen

- **[Windows Identity Foundation Overview](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/P09-21)**
- **[Identity Developer Training Course](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/IdentityTrainingCourse/)**

Also have you downloaded the **[WIF SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C148B2DF-C7AF-46BB-9162-2C9422208504&displaylang=en)**? You'll need the **[WIF runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb9c345f-e830-40b8-a5fe-ae7a864c4d76&displaylang=en)** installed before installing the SDK. The SDK contains a compiled HTML file that has a lot of good information on the WIF API inside (perhaps the best documentation at this moment that I've found along with the **[Windows Identity Foundation Whitepaper for developers](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/D/0/7D0B5166-6A8A-418A-ADDD-95EE9B046994/WindowsIdentityFoundationWhitepaperForDevelopers-RTW.pdf)**).

Comment: Russ - Yes, I've downloaded WIF runtime. I didn't realize it has a SDK too. I'll check out the developer training course and I do have the whitepaper.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find webcasts and tutorials:

[Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx)

Comment: There are a few webcasts, but not as indepth as their WCF series.